# Unwind segue for UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I'm using a UITableViewController to show a list of items for editing.  Once a row is tapped, it takes the user to a view controller to edit the data.

I want to use an unwind segue when they exit the edit screen via the default < (back) button, but I can't figure out how to connect it to Exit (to link the unwind segue) in the storyboard editor.

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

(I hope I don't have to create my own < (back) button.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're passing data backwards - then use delegates. Otherwise just add a button yourself to the bar and connect it like any other UIBarButtonItem. Then add the unwise segue.

Personally, I'd use delegates for this situation.

Comment: Which delegate method tells me that I've just tapped the <(back) button and am heading back to the tableview?